# Rockshox Reverb dropper seatpost squashing from new

Tags: mountain-bike, seatpost, dropper

I have a new bike with factory-fitted Reverb Stealth dropper seatpost. Having never had one before, I would like to know what movement you would expect on a seatpost if any. If I lift the bike up by the saddle, the post extends a bit if it’s not already at the top of its extension. This may be normal but I wanted to check.

The movement I’m getting that is more concerning is the squash that I get on the seat. It drops up to 1 cm. I’m not sure whether it needs a bleed, air pressure check or what. Any thoughts?

Comment: A dropper post when its locked should feel just like a "normal" post. Take it back to the shop where you bought it and get them to fix it. Also https://forums.mtbr.com/shocks-suspension/rs-reverb-stealth-squishy-top-948001.html

Comment: Thanks. I had read that thread but I wasn’t sure what the normal post should act like. I’ll get on to the shop and see what they say.

Answer (score 1):

> If I lift the bike up by the saddle, the post extends a bit if it’s not already at the top of its extension.

Yes, it is normal. reverb works like that.

> It drops up to 1 cm

Also possible and fine.

Just do regular maintanance and it will last.

Comment: I found a quick fix to get rid of a lot or the squashing symptoms. Extend the seat, flip the bike upside down and then push the bike down with the remote button pressed. Flip the bike back over and the seat should feel much better. Accidentally pulling the seat up draws air in to the oil chamber which is where the problem lies. This quick hack makes it tolerable.